# How to rid Contacts app of phone numbers showing as duplicate entries

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

**Problem description:**

This is the typical *duplicate contacts* scenario where a contact name does not show up when being called by that number. The problem is, *named* contacts have been duplicated into their *phone number formatted* counterparts. This has seemingly been caused by WhatsApp as only contacts with WhatsApp have been duplicated.

I.E., at the time the duplication occurred, Contacts app had 600 named contacts which "automatically" duplicated into 470 numbered contacts. Therefore, 1070 contacts exist, with no way to merge.

**Research and solution attempts:**

- Contacts > Settings > Merge duplicate contacts, produces no result
- Contacts > Settings > Contacts to Display > Custom List > Deselect WhatsApp contacts, shows only the named contacts but still doesn't show the named contact when being called.
- Syncing the contacts to Google, only syncs the *named* contacts, so merging cannot happen there
- Refreshing contacts in WhatsApp produces no result

**Other information:**

- CLI (Caller Line Identity) is turned on and had always worked prior to the issue arising - most notably if a named contact does not have WhatsApp, the contact name shows when being called currently.
- Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with Android version 7.0

**Partial Working Solution:**

- Deleting *numbered* contacts 1 by 1, produces "You cannot delete contacts from read-only accounts, but you can hide them in contacts." [Cancel] [Delete]

`Clicking [Delete] does produce the desired result but I'm looking for a more elegant fix. For lack of better words, to merge all named contacts and numbered contacts, without deleting them 1 by 1.`

Comment: Try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.compelson.optimizer). I bought after testing it. YMMMV